# Fail to connect remotely to Spark Master node inside a docker container

Tags: apache-spark, docker, pyspark

I created a spark cluster based in this [link](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop-spark-workbench).

Everything went smooth but the problem is after the cluster created im trying to use pyspark to connect remotely to the container inside the host from other machine.

I'm receiving a `18/04/04 17:14:48 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master xxxx.xxxx:7077` even though i can connect through telnet to the 7077 port from that host!

What may i be missing out?